# iPhone: Error-'this provisioning profile does not have a valid signature'?

Tags: iphone

In Developer program portal, 
I created a developer certificate. I registered for my iPhone deice. And registered an App ID (In App Purchase enabled). I created a provisioning profile using the created certificate and app id details. 
I followed the procedure that Apple said and created it.

I downloaded the provisioning profile and installed on Xcode and on the device.

I tried to install my application on my jailbroken iPhone device( i did jailbroken already) using the provisioning profile which i downloaded, but it throws an error as 'this provisioning profile does not have a valid signature or it has a valid but untrusted signature(or it has a valid but untrusted signature)'.

Can some one advise me what is wrong here and how to resolve it?

NOT YET RESOLVED WITH THE SUGGESTIONS PROVIDED UPTO NOW. ANY HELP PLEASE?

Martin/

Answer (score 3):

I had the very same issue although I set up provisioning, entitlements etc. correctly.

One cause of the error is described in http://www.onidev.com/2010/01/12/the-application-does-not-have-a-valid-signature/

**Certain folder names may not be used in your app bundle.** Check especially your "Copy files" build phases.

It seems this correlates with typical Apple app bundle names.

**Unallowed folder names** include (but are probably not limited to):

- `resources`
- `contents`

Renaming my folder from `contents` to `myContents` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the developer certificate and the corresponding private key to your keychain?

Comment: Yes. I added developer certificate  and private key in keychain access. If my iPhone is jailbroken, can i still use Apple's Provisioning profile and try download app via Xcode right? Then what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you have to add your own certificate (iPhone Developer: Johny Appleseed) you must also add Apple's Certificate Assigning Authority to your local keychain as well.

EDIT:

The [certificate section in the program portal](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) has the following info:

> Downloading and Installing Development
>   Certificates In the ‘Certificates’ >
>   ’Distribution’ section of the Portal,
>   control-click the WWDR Intermediate
>   Certificate link and select “Saved
>   Linked File to Downloads” to initiate
>   download of the certificate. On your
>   local machine, double-click the WWDR
>   Intermediate certificate to launch
>   Keychain Access and install. Upon CSR
>   approval, Team Members and Team Admins
>   can download their certificates via
>   the ‘Certificates’ section of the
>   Program Portal. Click ‘Download’ next
>   to the certificate name to download
>   your iPhone Development Certificate to
>   your local machine. On your local
>   machine, double-click the downloaded
>   .cer file to launch Keychain Access
>   and install your certificate. Team
>   Members can only download their own
>   iPhone Development Certificates. Team
>   Admins have the authority to download
>   the public certificates of all of
>   their Team Members. Apple never
>   receives the private key for a CSR.
>   The private keys are not available to
>   anyone except the original key pair
>   creator and are stored in the system
>   keychain of that Team Member.

The certificate assigning authority should be something like `applewwdrca.cer`, there are screen shots and more info in the "How To" section.

EDIT 2:

Read through this [Provisioning HowTo](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/provisioningprofiles/howto.action) carefully (as well as the other HowTo tabs in the program portal), provisioning is a pain in the ass tedious process, if this documentation does not fix your problem then you need to burn one of your free support cards and call Apple because there is a problem with your particular machine.  You should have gotten 2 of those support requests when you entered the program, if you used them all you can buy more.

Comment: I have added only certificate which i created through apple's site (Ex: iPhone Developer: <name>) into key chain access. I don't know about how to add 'Apple's Certificate Assigning Authority' also? Can you please explain more on it a bit?

Comment: I did that too. i.e Downloaded and installed both the certificates WWDR and my certificate. Both are in KeyChain access now. But still when i try to download my app through Xcode, it says 'this provisioning profile does not have a valid signature or it has a valid but untrusted signature(or it has a valid but untrusted signature)'. Please give me some other suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: Unfortunately this happens to Xcode from time to time, what has worked for me in the past is: rebooting, ensuring xcode is not running when placing the provisioning profile manually into ~library, rebooting some more, etc  I haven't found a reliable resolution

Comment: Remember to place the file into /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/  when xcode is not running

Comment: Also, ensure that your Identifier (Target info > Properties tab) matches your provision profile exactly eg. com.company.FooApp

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you mean that if i close Xcode and then copy provisional file in <user>/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ folder and then try installing, will resolve the problem?

Comment: My AppID is something like this -> com.mycompanyname.myappname so i added bundle identifier in my Xcode project as com.mycompanyname.myappname.${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier} Is it correct (or) it should be only com.mycompanyname.myappname (or) it should be without dot(.) as com.mycompanyname.myappname${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier}